# Decompression sickness vs man who has teleportation ability

Tags: internal-consistency, super-powers, teleportation

Suppose my opponent is able to teleport everywhere (an example). Also he has strong combat skills. 
I can't beat him in face to face combat but i able to keep fighting for some time. Also i can force him to teleport away from me to some "safe" place (threatening to blow up both of us, for example).

So i have an idea: **Decompression sickness**

What if i lure him to the place with high atmospheric pressure and keep him in this place for some time. Then i will force him to teleport into place with normal pressure and will wait.

So my question is: Is it look possible? And if yes what about details?

- Which type of place with high pressure i should prefer?
- Which value of pressure enough to hurt or kill my opponent.
- How long i should keep him in this place.
- How much time in place with normal pressure is needed to induce
  Decompression sickness.

Also i want to crank it as quietly (for my opponent) as possible.
Of course i want to stay alive after all.

PS Sorry for my poor English

Comment: Why would your opponent be forced to teleport to someplace when he can teleport anywhere ? Even if you threaten to blow him up with yourself , the choice is completely his to make.

Comment: Check out the *Jumper* series of novels for ways where the villian and jumper outsmart each other in various forms of traps.

Comment: I suspect exposing him to a flu virus is just as dangerous, and easier to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

If you could lure him into a [recompression chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recompression_chamber) or [caisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caisson_(engineering)_(engineering)), and crank it to a couple atmospheres, equivalent to 100 feet down, then keep him in there for a little while, then he could develop the bends.

Even better if he went from the chamber to a higher altitude. Like an airplane or mountain fortress.

Edit:
As to how long, you'd have to consult some dive tables, which are a little confusing:
[image]

However, if I'm understanding it, at 100 feet you'd only need to keep him in the chamber for 3 minutes before sudden decompression would start to cause problems.

Comment: Clearly this means that your Evil Lair should be a deep sea research station.  <Cue evil laughter>

Comment: Those tables have a fairly decent safety margin built in. And the seriousness of symptoms is, generally, in direct proportion to the time spent at depth, and speed of ascent. (also why they generally don't recommend air travel afterwards.)

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously an obvious answer, but underwater. Maybe take a hostage with you to the ocean depths, in a submarine that's too small for the hero to teleport into (and then out of, taking the hostage with him).

Answer (score -3):

If you can forcibly teleport him anywhere and prevent him from returning instantly, why bother with decompression sickness?

Teleport him to the moon (I dont know exact timeframe for death, but 5 minutes are a sure kill), the sun (couple of seconds is enough) or bottom of marinara trench (again, couple of seconds).

Comment: No i can't force him to teleport anywhere. I can just force him to teleport away from me (threatening to blow up both of us, for example). I am sorry for bad formulation. (Post already edited)

Comment: But then your decompression sickness trick doesn't work as, assuming he is smart, he'll teleport to a place with the same pressure. By the way, on the surface of the sun it wouldn't take even a second for you to die, would be almost instantaneously as your brain vaporizes.

Comment: @Selenog Good point. I hope that my opponent not so smart/careful. Also i cannot imagine way which force enemy to teleport to the sun.